# How to proper use Flysystem and Local Adapter

Tags: php, shopware6, flysystem

Since I couldn’t find a proper documentation and examples for flysystem, I am asking you for help. Currently I am developing a plugin (for Shopware 6), and I am using some sources that are stored inside my plugin (such as pictures, and csv files). 
The structure looks like this

```
|-- custom
   |-- plugins
       |-- ImporterPlugin
          |-- src
            |-- Adapter
              |-- CsvImportAdapter.php
              |-- ImportAdapterInterface.php
            |-- Command
              |-- ImportCommand.php
            |-- Factory
              |-- AdapterFactory.php
            |-- Resources
            |-- Service
            |-- ImporterPlugin.php
          |-- upload
            |-- product.csv
            |-- media
              |-- Image1.jpg
```

Inside .env I wrote the file paths that I need

```
IMPORT_CSV_PATH=/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ImporterPlugin/upload/products.csv
IMPORT_MAP_PATH=/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ImporterPlugin/src/Resources/maps/product.map.json

PRODUCTIMPORTER_MEDIA_SOURCE_PATH=/var/www/html/custom/plugins/ImporterPlugin/upload/media/
```

My question is, how can I implement Local Adapter (Flysystem)? And where to call functions / methods? The functionality of the plugin is mainly called in command line. Please provide some examples. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Flysystem has a good documentation at https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/

Comment: Probelm is that I got the concept in my head, but stuck at realising. I don't know if building additional classes (factories, adapters) are okay. As well, I don't know where should I call the methods that reads my path and where to store the path. Thanks for your time

Comment: Writing code is mostly okay if you need to develop a plugin. Whether that is necessary or not depends on many things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `services.xml` of your plugin you can use the `FileSystemFactory` and a collection of arguments to define your filesystem abstraction.

```xml
<service class="League\Flysystem\FilesystemInterface" id="importer_plugin.filesystem.private" public="true">
    <factory service="Shopware\Core\Framework\Adapter\Filesystem\FilesystemFactory" method="factory"/>
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="type">local</argument>
        <argument key="config" type="collection">
            <argument key="root">%kernel.plugin_dir%/ImporterPlugin/upload</argument>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</service>
```

You can then inject `importer_plugin.filesystem.private` into your other services and work with the filesystem abstraction rooted in the `upload` directory.

```php
public function __construct(FilesystemInterface $filesystem)
{
    $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
}

// ...

$products = $this->filesystem->read('products.csv');
```